# Settings for pandas_dedupe to stop automatically printing

Tags: pandas

Are there any settings for pandas-dedupe to stop automatically printing. It always prints

```
Importing data ...
Reading from link_dataframes_learned_settings
Clustering...
# duplicate sets x
```

I want it to not print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s actually possible to stop those printed messages, even without modifying the library. Use a context manager that gobbles up the printed output, so it doesn’t go to your screen.

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    # Any code here (like calling that library function) won’t print anything.
    df_final = pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(df,['first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_initial'])
print("I still want this line to print.")
```

`redirect_stdout` is commonly used to send your printed output to a different file, or to the standard error stream. If you instead provide `None` as the argument, the output goes nowhere.

Comment: Sorry—can you explain?

Comment: Thanks Arya. This is a good trick, I agree. 

Quick comment that might help others in the future: I would reminder users that this only work when deduplicating data (or linking dataframe) _and_  the data has been labelled using active learning (i.e. *_setting and *_json files have already been created). Otherwise, the library won't work.

Also, the user won't have a information about which *_setting file is used nor what steps the library is currently implementing. This might not be ideal for some users.

Comment: If the user didn't want anything printed ("I want it not to print anything."), I assume they know the risk of not knowing which step is being executed. That's true for any program, not just those using your package.

Comment: This trick will not break any functionality of your library; your comment may mistakenly cause readers to believe that this simple context manager is limited in either _when_ you can use it, or _whether_ your library will work when it's used. I wanted to clear that up.

Comment: pandas-dedupe uses the `input()` function during active learning. 
If you run `input()` with `contextlib`, you might get an error.
This is what I get from my setup at the moment. 

Mine is a simple warning. As I said in my previous comment, your answer is good. And I agree with it. I'm not sure why you are so resentful.
This is my last comment to this post. Peace.

Comment: I’m merely confused by your claims, not resentful. I want readers to have a clear understanding of problems, and nowhere in the repository for pandas-dedupe can I find an invocation of `input`. If I’ve missed it, I still don’t know what could lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintener of pandas-dedupe.

Thank for your interest in the library.
At the moment there is no setting to stop automatic printing.

Feel free to open an issue on the [pandas-dedupe github page](https://github.com/Lyonk71/pandas-dedupe) if this is an essential feature for your work. Also, we are happy to receive a PR, if you want.